# Create Items in the other list on create of list item and same for CRUD operations with SharePoint Online/Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, office-365, rest, designer-workflow

I've two site collections **A** & **B**.

Collection A & B contains custom lists **ListA & ListB** with the same column name(Both the lists are identical)

I have to create items in the **ListA** & that item should be **created in the ListB** & this is applicable for the rest of the operations like update & delete too.

Is it possible with workflow? I think we can do the Add & Update but I don't have any idea about delete!

How can I achive this?

Comment: No one have any idea?